# Which Philosopher would you recommend for learning about the implied philosophy of gifted education?

Tags: pragmatism, education, critical-theory

I'm searching for a philosopher who either commented on gifted education or someone whose writings would critique/applaud gifted education in America.  Someone who might be (or have been) a vocal opponent or proponent of gifted education.  Please feel free to share your suggestions/comments/concerns.  I appreciate all feedback

Philosophers that I am investigating

Paulo Freire

Maria Montessori

Herbert Spencer

John Dewey

Comment: Santayana, his work The Life Of Reason. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Life_of_Reason

Comment: Btw, thank you for giving the name of Paulo Freire!  I was not familiar with his work.